# xamarin - How to set each new capture photo to each frame?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using [this](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) plugin to take a photo and I've successfully created a command function to return the image stream and bind the source. In my app, I have 3 frames/boxes and each new captured photo should be on the frame.

Ex:
the first captured photo should be on the first frame then when I capture 
again(which is now second photo) it should be on the second frame.

this is how I do the binding for the image.

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="FirstPhoto" Aspect="AspectFit"LoadingPlaceholder="loader.gif" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
```

My question is how I will set each new captured photo on each frame?

[image]

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have multiple ImagePath (ie, ImagePath1, ImagePath2, ImagePath3) properties in your model, and after you take each photo update the appropriate property.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for answering :). Is that the only way to do this? So if I have let the user to capture 5 photos I need 5 ImagePath then.

Comment: You could have a List<string> that stores the paths, and then bind them using index notation.  Or use a horizontal List or a Repeater and bind that to the list of paths